# vscode change linenumber color

Tags: themes, ide, visual-studio-code

How can I change the color of the line numbers in VS code

[image]

Often times the line numbers are to dark to make out.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Version 1.12](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_12) introduced new workbench theming options (they were experimental in 1.11).

There is a setting for the color of line numbers:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorLineNumber.foreground": "#999999"
}
```

Some themes also define current line number:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorLineNumber.activeForeground": "#555555"
}
```

See the [Theme Color Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color).

Comment: This also works for CodeSandbox, for anyone looking for how to change the line number  color there (it is pretty dim!)

Comment: More info about the issue with the default CodeSandbox theme here: https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/3824#issuecomment-607957131

Comment: Any way to control the background of the overall "line number sidebar"?

Answer (score 6):

@jerclarke If you want to change the background color of the sidebar containing the row numbers, use:

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorGutter.background" : "#393a39"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be an option to tweak individual colors from a color theme in VSCode (yet?), but there are many color themes to choose from (built-in and 3rd-party), and they do post instructions on how to design your own color theme:

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/themes

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 RC it can be done as followed:
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Line Number

 Don't know if it's the same is VS Code, sorry if it isn't.